# How to install the pylzma library on Linux?

Tags: python-2.7, lzma, py7zlib, pylzma

The pylzma library is a requirement for another tool that I would like to use. I am new to python and programming and have a few questions:

I have already followed the procedure to download and install pylzma from the following site since it seems to be the easiest:
https://code.google.com/p/threadzip/wiki/InstallingPylzma

But I get stuck at the byte compile py7zlib part.

How do I byte compile py7zlib?

When I check the documentation on the authors page http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/ and go to the designated folder I see the following files:

In the /tmp/pylzma-0.4.6/build/lib.linux-i686-2.7 folder I see:
    py7lib.py        py7zlib.pyc      pylzma.so

But no the "py7zlib.pwd" as stated on the authors page however I do see the "py7zlib.pyc" as stated on the original page listed.

Do I still need to compile this bytecode?

When I "import py7lib" in at the python prompt I see nothing, no feedback or error.
How do I check to see if this has been correctly imported and that I have installed this library correctly?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I think this is probably a better question for the [Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added this question to the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange also. Thanks!